# Create an alarm using DialogAlert

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to set an alarm upon clicking a button from an AlertDialog? I want to create an alarm when the snooze button of the AlertDialog is clicked.

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Snooze",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  //@Override


        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)  {

            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");


            PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
            EditText text=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String str = text.getText().toString();
            long t=Long.parseLong(str);
             alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                     time+( t*60*1000), operation);


        }
    });
```

ERROR:

```
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.example.servicealarmdemo2.AlertDemo$2.onClick(AlertDemo.java:60)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-22 19:52:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Check out [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), try it, then come back if you encounter difficulties.

Comment: I have tried but some methods were undefined for the Alert Dialog class

Comment: such as getBaseContext and getSystemService

Comment: They are obviously defined but in some other way. Just post your code with the error and we will help you.

Comment: I have updated my code please check it above I couldn't complie it the error was "The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=124). Go through it, try to figure it out, spend a lot of time on it. You learn best when you push yourself to your limit.Then when someone gives a good response, accept their answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Good luck and welcome to Android!

Comment: Thank You for reply I have seen this tutorial before but I am looking for creating an alarm upon clicking on a negative button from Dialog Interface so these differ I have tried to set the alarm using the described method but didn't work :(

Comment: AndroidWarrior, the link to that tutorial is now broken. Can you link me to working tutorial or just update your answer? I am curious about this too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getActivity().getBaseContext()` with `getActivity()`.

Comment: I have tried that also but didn't work : error:"The method getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, int, Intent, int)"

Comment: This method also is not defined . The problem is that I'm not able to get the context of the PendingIntent I can only retrieve Fragment/DialogFragment.

Comment: I guess I can solve this problem: PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); I will test it hope it work

Comment: If it's a fragment then only **getActivity()** will work. You should have mentioned Fragment.

Comment: Yes :( It gives a NPE

Comment: What is line 60 of your AlerDemo class??

Comment: String str = text.getText().toString();

Comment: I want to get the time of the snooze as a string and parse it to long